# Stop performing remaining tasks in airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have three tasks `t1,t2,t3`. each task output is next task input for eg., `t1` output is `t2` input. After completion of `t1`, I am getting an empty output folder(which can happen in my case and it is acceptable and marked `t1` as success) but `t2` is failed to fetch the output of `t1` as there are no files. I want to mark `t2` and `t3` as success if there are no files. How can I skip the next two tasks.

---

I went through the airflow docs and other articles came across sensors and poke method. But, not sure how to proceed with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can leverage a [SensorOperator](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#basesensoroperator) more specifically the [FileSensorOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/sensors/file_sensor.py) to check if a file exists. You can then use the [soft_fail](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator.py#L38) arg to mark the tasks as "skipped" when the file does not exist. This will allow the DAG to succeed while maintaining the proper history of what occurred on the file check.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help! I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The @andscoop's answer is good, but only in order to bring more ideas:

#### Possible solution 1

I'm doing something similar (dependencies A > B > C) and I've solved the approach using the XCOM pushed by default by the previous task.

> Any value that the execute method returns is saved as an Xcom message
>   under the key `return_value`. We’ll cover this topic later.
>   Source http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2017/03/19/developing-workflows-with-apache-airflow/

```
# copy&paste it into dags/stackoverflow.py to test it

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from datetime import datetime


dag = DAG('stackoverflow', description='Another Dag',
          schedule_interval='* * * 1 1',
          start_date=datetime(2018, 6, 27), catchup=False)


def do_a(**kwargs):
    # Assuming that your TASK A is not returning a value
    return None


task_a = PythonOperator(task_id='do_a',
                        python_callable=do_a,
                        provide_context=True,
                        dag=dag)


def do_b(**kwargs):
    result_from_a = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='do_a')
    if result_from_a:
        print("Continue with your second task")
    else:
        print("Send a notification somewhere, log something or stop the job here.")


task_b = PythonOperator(task_id='do_b',
                        python_callable=do_b,
                        provide_context=True,
                        dag=dag)
task_a >> task_b
```

[image]
[image]

#### Possible solution 2

Branching. In a more sophisticated way (and using the best practices) you can do a branch to determinate the next step/task based on the result of `t1`. I can't do a proper example now but here 2 sources to understand how it works with examples:

- https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator.py
- https://github.com/geosolutions-it/evo-odas/wiki/Airflow---about-subDAGs,-branching-and-xcom